# Asp.NET Sessions dropping with "In Process" setting. Can someone clarify some things for me?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7

I have a web application that appears to be randomly dropping ASP.NET sessions. This application is hosted across four servers along with a load balancer. I have looked at the Session State settings in IIS7 for the site's virtual directory. Each server has this set to "In Process". From some reading I have done, it looks like this means the session data is only held on a single server, and if the load balancer switches the server on that user, the session will get dropped. Is this correct?

Articles that I have read also state that if using "In Process" when hosting on multiple servers, you should be using something called "Sticky Sessions", but don't go much into detail about it.  How I can check to see if "Sticky Sessions" are being used? Is this an IIS7 setting, something unique to the load balancer, or something totally different?

This is just my theory, so I am also wondering if there are some other indicators I should look into before I can draw the conclusion or eliminate the possibility that the load balancer/IIS settings are the issue.

I've checked into the Event Viewer and I don't think this is happening due to any recycling of AppPools or IIS itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, when another server is hit in one of next requests, there is no data.

Sticky sessions are handled by the balancer. It could stick clients by their ip or issue a stick cookie. Depends on the actual balancer and now it is configured. In NLB this was called "session affinity".

Another common workaround would be to configure your session to a sql server mode but sounds like you are aware of this possibility and you don't want to go that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Wiktor Zychla. If I may, I have a follow up. I just heard back from our operations department and they have informed me that we actually do not have a load balancer. Instead we have a DNS CNAME with multiple IPs assigned to it. I think this supports my original theory that sessions are getting dropped, because users are getting sent to multiple servers. Do you agree?  I am thinking it might make sense to go to SQL Server mode route now.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have much choice but to have your sessions in the database. The configuration takes just few minutes. On the other hand, setting up the NLB or ARR as balancers is also rather straightforward and you could recommend them to at least consider this at some point in future.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wiktor. I have also had reports of users wandering into other users sessions. I am thinking this might be due to the same issue.